# How Can I Generate a Webapp in Yeoman With Support for RequireJS?

Tags: requirejs, yeoman

If I recall correctly, the yeoman webapp generator used to offer support for RequireJS. Now I can't figure out how to get it running with RequireJS. I've got version 0.4.6 of generator-webapp installed globally, and 1.0.6 of Yeoman.

Comment: this commit on github is relevant: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/commit/f53d0d49e2f8c334494d782e6620f6c4bf36d41d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fork available to install via `npm -g install generator-webapp-rjs` (https://npmjs.org/package/generator-webapp-rjs), but there is also a PR for adding requirejs back into generator-webapp: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/pull/241
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/commit/f53d0d49e2f8c334494d782e6620f6c4bf36d41d#commitcomment-5240746

Comment: this is looking promising.

Answer (score 1):

They [dropped the support for requirejs](https://github.com/intimidate/generator-webapp_requirejs/commit/a4ccc48ef169a063bd18e969a7e5446f66a4be87). But can find good alternatives. Try `npm search yeoman-generator` to find all the available generators. Some of them are for both angular and requirejs. This one look promising: https://github.com/marcol/generator-alchemy